# How to increase number of visible hairs in particle edit mode?

Tags: particles, hair

I've made some hair using 'Quick Fur' effect. I've also changed how they look (individual hairs are much wider now, because of the look I was trying to achieve) and I've reduced the number of hair, because it didn't look good with too high number anymore.

The problem is, while it looks fine in render or object mode, when I enter particle edit I can only see a couple of them. Like two orders of magnitude less. It makes it very difficult to work in this mode - since I can barely see effects before switching back to object mode or rendering.

Is hair in particle edit in some low preview (how to change it?) Or am I missing something (since I'm a almost complete newb)?

Comment: could you add a screen shot or this?

Comment: Not right know (I'm at work). But essentially it would just show model with lot's of hair in object mode and only a few in particle edit.

Comment: On the bottom left of blender there is a "children" checkbox to turn children viewing on in Particle Edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be that you have children visualized (default enabled in quick fur)?

this is with children, as in quick fur, and they are visible only in object/render mode (I think there's no way to visualize children during editmode). You could convert from the modifier panel to a real mesh, perhaps, so that children become "real", but you'll loose particle behaviour...

[image]

which in particle edit mode becomes

[image]

and this is the same mesh without children, in object and edit mode

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, you are right, didn't noticed that.